# Rails partial template rendering repeatedly when a helper method uses the yield keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, renderpartial, yield-keyword

I have seen some strange behavior when using rails with partial layouts plus a helper method coded as an iterator using the yield keyword. I am hoping someone can:

1. Explain what's going on and why I get the duplicate rendering and maybe
2. Suggest an alternate approach, hopefully other than just re-coding my helper method to be a simple function that returns a list (I've already done that as an interim workaround)

So if I create the following 3 things in my rails 3 app, I get unexpected output.

[UPDATE]
I have tested the following combinations:

```
Rails 3.0.0 + erb (has this issue)
Rails 3.0.0 + haml (OK)
Rails 3.0.3 + erb (has this issue)
Rails 3.0.3 + haml (OK)
```

So maybe it's an erb vs. haml thing, but when I initially discovered this it was on haml templates.  Hmmm....anyone know what's going on???

A) A main template that looks like this (app/views/main/index.html.erb)

```
  <h1>Main#index</h1>
  <p>This is content from main#index before the partial template rendering
  <%= render :partial => "partial" %>
  <p>This is content from main#index after the partial template rendering.</p>
```

B) A helper method like this (app/helpers/main_helper.rb)

```
  module MainHelper

    def my_iterator
      yield 1
      yield 2
      yield 3
      yield 4
    end
  end
```

C) A partial template like this (app/views/main/_partial.html.erb)

```
  <% my_iterator do |x| %>
  <p>iterator running with <%= x %></p>
  <% end %>
```

When I view the result in the browser, I see the "iterator running with" block a total of 8 times (1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4).  I have determined it is the yield within my_iterator screwing with the rails partial template mechanism.  If I code my_iterator as follows, the output is as I would expect. (I also need to change my partial template to do my_iterator.each)

```
def my_iterator
  logger.debug("my_iterator called")
  return [1, 2, 3, 4]
end
```

Is there a way to code this such that I don't screw with rails and get duplicate rendering but can still code a helper method as an iterator using yield? Also, can someone explain exactly how the duplicate rendering happens?

Comment: FYI, I'm not getting this behavior in Rails 3.0.3 with Haml.

Comment: I'll try with 3.0.3 and see if it goes away.

Comment: Tried it with rails 3.0.3. Same problem. FYI I am using haml in production where I initially found this problem but using erb for the question here for simplicity but both seem to exhibit this.

Comment: Ah. Interesting, monocle.  I coded the same scenario but with the haml template engine and in my little test app, the problem is not there in rails 3.0.3.

Comment: Confirming this problem with Rails 3.0.3 on Ruby 1.8.7p0. Does not occur on Rails 2.3.8 though. Also, see if this ticket is relevant: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2279-render-layout-with-block-and-multiple-yields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just having a very similar issue and just managed to solve it. I believe the original helper above would work as expected if rewritten it as such...

```
module MainHelper
  def my_iterator(&block)
    block.call(1)
    block.call(2)
    block.call(3)
    block.call(4)
  end
end
```

The same problem seems to occur in Rails 3 if your calling `concat(capture(&block))` or `concat(block.call)`.  In both cases, just drop the `concat()` and the duplicate rendering vanishes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jon!  I'm not currently focused on this project anymore but next time I go back to it to make some updates I'll try this out and let you know the results.

Comment: Actually, again I have it working OK in development and rendering twice in production. Still stumped.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a similar problem which only appeared in production, not development. I narrowed this down to

```
    config.action_view.cache_template_loading = true
```

in my development.rb.  When set to true, I saw a elements in my haml file.  By adding and removing blocks I narrowed down the offending code to

```
    = if @user.bio
      = @user.bio
```

which was causing the entire block which preceded this to be re-printed.  Simply replacing = with - solves this.  It was awkward to debug simply because I had to do in debug in production mode.

My advice is to look for errant = outputs on logical operators.

```
    - if @user.bio
      = @user.bio
```

Answer (score 0):

Using content_for within a helper will append content on each iteration. You can write a ApplicationHelper method to yield content within helpers like so:

```
def yield_content(content_key)
  view_flow.content.delete(content_key)
end
```

Then use yield_content instead of content_for within your other helper files.